Difference between the measure words 节, 堂, and 门?
I’m trying to understand the differences between the measure words 节, 堂, and 门 when referring to classes in a school setting. This is because I have seen people in multiple instances use "节" very blurrily, as a fill-in for times when the latter two "堂" and "门" may be the correct one.
Here’s my understanding:
节 (jié) Period
time, divison of time (时间的分段), segments
Refers to specific class periods (segments) or lessons within a schedule.
i.e. 
“我跟他上（同）一节数学课。”
I take the same (period) of math class as him.

"我今天下午和我的朋友一起上一节数学课。"
"This afternoon, I have a period of math class with my friend."


Used for specific class periods or lessons, referring to segments.

i.e. first period (第一节) and second period (第二节)


The character 节 has the imagery of bamboo (竹节), characterized by segmented lines along its body.
This imagery suggests the idea of dividing things into parts (事物的分节、分段).
Due to the character "节"'s relation to bamboo, 节 also carries the meaning of "segments," as seen in the word 季节 (jìjié), which refers to seasons and indicates a period of time (时期) in a year.
Exemplify in the Chinese term for chapters: "章节" (章内分节; segments within a chapter)
Isolated time block

堂 (táng) Session
set duration, sessions, specific instance (特定时间)
Number of classes in session (课堂进行中的次数)
i.e.
“今天我们上了一堂关于环保的课。”
"Today, we had a class (session) on environmental protection."


Emphasizes the (entire) set duration or experience of the lesson.
Refers to a specific class session (duration) or lesson.
Emphasizes the experience of attending the class.
Used for lessons regardless of their length.


门 (mén) Subject
subject(科目), course (课程), a class
Refers to entire academic subjects or courses...
The whole subject rather than specific lessons or sessions.
i.e.
“我有三门课要上：数学、英语和物理。”
"I have three subjects to take: math, English, and physics."


Used to classify different disciplines a student is studying.
Can indicate the number of subjects a student is taking, as in “我有三门课要上：数学、英语和物理。”

Refers to number of classes, rather than a specific class period. (often mistaken with 节)





Examples that clarify the distinction between 门 and 节:
Course: Entirety (门) vs Segment (节)
“今天我有两门课：数学和英语。其中，第一节是数学课，第二节是英语课。”
"Today, I have two subjects: math and English. The first period is math class, and the second period is English class.

“今天我有两门课，其中一节是和我的朋友一起上的。”
"Today, I have two classes, one of which I am taking a period with my friend."
- In this second example, the first part of the sentence "我有两门课" can be interchangeable with "我有两节课" as the number of classes (门) and the segments of the class in your schedule (节) both works.

“下学期这门美术课就一节。而且是梅老师教的。”
“There is only one period of art for this course next semester. It is taught by Mr. Mei.”

“我以前上过一（门/节）关于教导迟缓学生如何阅读的课。”
"I took a (course/period) about teaching delayed students how to read."
***- This is an IMPORTANT example, as it shows how based on the context (,which measure word you use,) it will affect the whole sentence.）***

Examples that clarify the distinction between 堂 and 节:
Class Session: Whole (堂) vs Part (节)
“请问两节(驾驶)课的费用是多少？什么？你们把两节组合成一堂课了？”
"May I ask how much the cost is for two (periods of driving) lessons? What? You combined two classes into one session?"
- (This is a real-life example that I noticed when going into driving school. The use between 堂 and 节 became blurry because of the complexity of the service they are providing.)


Summarized understanding:

“一节”: one lesson.

“一门”: the whole course.

“一堂”: one full session, but can be segmentized
  → “节”: segment of “堂”
  (often confused)




“一堂”: one full session, which can be segmentized.

ok i will edit that. thank you

节: 上课的时间段，一般是45 - 50 分钟。也是指书中的章节，是课程内容的分段。比如：
（1）明天上午只有两节课。然后去博物馆参观。
（2）明天考试第三章，但是不包括最后一节内容。
堂：是空间的概念，比如：课堂，礼堂，教堂。一堂课一般是指在一间教室里由一个老师给一个班的学生上一门课程。比如：
（3）这堂数学课我是真的糊涂了，一点儿都不懂。
（4）参观完生产车间，老师傅给我们上了一堂安全生产的现场课。
门：是课程的分类科目（分门别类）。比如：
（5）我这学期注册了三门课，可以得到十二个学分。
（6）高等数学和高等代数不是一门课。
I suggest that we first study the meanings of the words in their original language (Chinese) and then translate them into English or other languages. Otherwise, we might wonder what is the difference between this session (节) and that session (堂).

From my experience, both 节 and 堂 mean session.
If there’s a short break in the middle of a class, those two parts are usually called 上（or 前）半节课 and 下（or 后）半节课.
If I want to mention a specific segment in a session, I will use 一会/xx分钟. For example, 这节课很无聊，他听了一会（or maybe 二十分钟）就离开了.

oh, that makes sense. As both 节 and 堂, while each has their meanings, can be used to express session of a class. It is like how in driving school, sometimes they use either one based on the school.

When used as a measured word for class sessions, the difference between 堂 and 節 is almost not noticeable, even the dictionary defines each as:
汉典(zdic.net)
堂 〈量〉- 用于分节的课程。如:一堂课
節 〈量〉- 用于分段的事物。如:两节车厢;三节课
However, here is another view that sounds more logical (to me):

"堂 refers to the (class)room (the original meaning of 堂), so it is technically different from 节. For example, if you encounter a course taking two lectures (节) in a row (but having a short interval break between them), it can still be called as 一堂课, but 两节课." https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/tpaam5/difference_between_measure_words_%E5%A0%82_and_%E8%8A%82_in/


I think I have read something similar to your understanding, Where 一节 is a segment. Therefore, 两节 can be the intervals of 一堂. However, when I notice people say “我上过一节关于##的课”。 While it makes sentence, I am wondering if "一门" makes more sense as it refers to the entire course.

It depends on the duration and length of the class taught. 一节课 is "one lesson" in a school day,  一門課 means "one course", which usually consists of many lessons in a semester, or through many semesters.
